# Microsoft Graph api: Is there a http header or url parameter that can be used with a http POST to cause it to do a PATCH instead?

Tags: http, microsoft-graph-api

Certain cloud SAAS providers are still using old versions of JAVA that do not support outbound rest calls with the PATCH verb.  I have an integration that I am writing that is hung up on this issue.  Does the graph api allow a POST call to have an additional optional parameter or similar functionality to make it behave as a PATCH or PUT? Google, for instance supports the HTTP header, "X-HTTP-Method-Override".  Does graph have any similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

No the Graph does not support that mechanism.  It is not a widely used capability anymore.  My best advice for the moment would be to stand up a proxy that does the conversion for you before calling the Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is such an override.  Using the header "X-HTTP-Method" with a value of PATCH will indeed turn a POST into a PATCH.

This was discovered while looking into some sharepoint api documentation for a different integration and the header was used in an example provided by microsoft.

Tested and works in both v1.0 and beta